# Bootstrap - Scrolling a fixed collapse menu

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

For my mobile site I have a trigger button that when clicked brings up a div that was initially collapsed. The div is fixed to top of the screen and takes up the whole screen height. In that div, there is an accordion menu list. I cannot scroll down my long menu list because of the element is fixed. When I set it to absolute, it puts it on the wrong area of the page (I guess relative to the previous div, not to the page).

Here's a demo. http://www.bootply.com/a2ryNdYbAw

I guess it would help to view on a phone so you can see the scrolling problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want the page to scroll when the accordion is extended out of view you can add `overflow: auto;` to the refine ID

See working Snippet.

*Sidenote: I also added `overflow: hidden` to `#refine.collapsing` so the right scroll bar is hidden when the accordion opens because simply looks better. This is independent of the scroll issue and can be removed if needed.

```css
#refine.collapsing {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#refine.collapse.in {
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
}
#refine {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  padding: 0 0px 10px 0px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #f00;
  border-top: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #828181;
  -moz-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #828181;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 4px -2px #828181;
  top: 0;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In enim ipsum, interdum non pharetra malesuada, scelerisque et ligula. Proin semper imperdiet semper. Cras porta pulvinar magna. Maecenas malesuada dui sed quam egestas accumsan. In vel interdum
      sapien, in pretium velit. Morbi tristique ligula eget nibh sollicitudin efficitur. Duis imperdiet, dui tincidunt semper facilisis, eros libero condimentum sem, ut venenatis elit tellus in ligula. Suspendisse venenatis aliquet velit, venenatis pharetra
      ligula. Ut lorem metus, vulputate sed ipsum nec, consequat posuere orci. Nulla libero nisl, lobortis a nibh sit amet, sagittis venenatis lacus. Ut sollicitudin sapien eget facilisis commodo. Nunc pharetra felis id sapien aliquet iaculis. Ut a ante
      mi. Donec hendrerit pretium sapien, in lacinia felis congue non. Sed in purus sit amet diam iaculis viverra. Mauris dapibus vulputate ultricies. Nunc nec mi condimentum, tincidunt ipsum nec, congue justo. Curabitur et eros ligula. Maecenas molestie
      arcu vitae tempor molestie. Aliquam sit amet nibh sem.</div>
  </div>

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">

      <a role="button" class="btn btn-block btn-footer-a btn-default" data-toggle="collapse" href="#refine">Filter by</a>
      <div class="collapse" id="refine">
        <div class="col-xs-12 refine-header">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3 vcenter">text</div>
            <div class="col-xs-7 vcenter text-right">text</div>
            <div class="col-xs-2 vcenter">text</div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12">
          <div class="panel-group" id="refine-accordion" role="tablist" aria-multiselectable="true">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                <div class="panel-title">
                  <a role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#refine-accordion" href="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="true" aria-controls="collapseOne" class="btn-block">
         Size
        </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Men's (23)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Ladies' (47)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Midsize (12)</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                <div class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed btn-block" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#refine-accordion" href="#collapseTwo" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseTwo">
          Case material
        </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Stainless Steel</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Steel and Yellow Gold</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Steel and Rose Gold</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                <div class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed btn-block" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#refine-accordion" href="#collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseThree">
          Band material
        </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                <div class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed btn-block" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#refine-accordion" href="#collapseFour" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFour">
          Dial color
        </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseFour" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-default">
              <div class="panel-heading" role="tab">
                <div class="panel-title">
                  <a class="collapsed btn-block" role="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#refine-accordion" href="#collapseFive" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseFive">
          Another
        </a>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div id="collapseFive" class="panel-collapse collapse" role="tabpanel">
                <div class="panel-body">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled">
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Blue (1)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Black (4)</li>
                    <li>
                      <input type="checkbox">Silver (23)</li>
                  </ul>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```